# Spinner select Item in android studio [ using parse ]

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform, onclicklistener, android-spinner

I have problem using Spinner in android studio 
I retreive my data from Parse.com and after that I take the array of list and use it as spinner , It was working but the problem when I try to get the value the user will select I try many codes that use [ onItemSelectedListner method ] when I press on the Item in the spinner It will not selected and doesn't appear as selected

so in the end I used this code which view the spinner ITEM inside the Query.findInTheBackground , however the problem that I want to get the value that user selected but I cant !! what should I do ?

and there is one more problem , when the spinner is shown the list is white so how can I change the color ?!

this is my code

```
public class AppointmentDetailSelection extends Activity {

protected Spinner aSpinner;
protected  ArrayList<String> nameList =new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment_detail_selection);

    aSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    getDepartmentList();

}

public void getDepartmentList (){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Doctors");
    query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("Department"));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (list == null) {
                Log.d("request failed.");
            } else {
                for (ParseObject comment : list) {
                    nameList.add(comment.getString("Department"));
                    Log.d("appointDate", "retrieved a related post");
                }
                ArrayAdapter adap = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nameList);
                aSpinner.setAdapter(adap);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into ParseQueryAdapter. What I'll do is:

AppointmentDetailSelection:

```
public class AppointmentDetailSelection extends Activity {

protected Spinner aSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment_detail_selection);
    aSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    DoctorsAdapter adapter = new DoctorsAdapter(this);
    aSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    aSpinner.setSelection(0);

}

private class DoctorsAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter {

        public DoctorsAdapter(final Context context) {
            super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

                public ParseQuery create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Doctors");
                    query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("Department"));
                    return query;
                }
            });
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView1;
            TextView textView2;
        }

        @Override
        public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.textView2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

            holder.textView1.setText(object.getString("field_from_db1"));
            holder.textView2.setText(object.getString("field_from_db2"));

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

your_custom_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your help , however I get a problem when I run the code ,  due to the              holder.textView1.setText(object.getString("field_from_db1"));
   and this is the error   :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for 'field_from_db1'. Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.

Comment: well, have you changed "field_from_db1" to whatever field you wish to pull from your DB?